# Timezone data cannot be found :

Tags: timezone, cockroachdb

When I run my jar file for CockroachDB, I'm seeing the below error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Asia/Calcutta"
Detail: timezone data cannot be found
```

I tried manually changing the timezone from UTC.

Comment: I am also getting the same error when I am trying to fetch data from local cockroach database table with spring data JPA

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB gets the named time zones information from the system.

The source differs based on the system:

- **Linux**: it likely means that the package `tzdata` is not installed. Installing it with your standard package manager should be sufficient.
- **OSX**: it should just be installed
- **Windows**: you might have some luck installing the [Go toolchain](https://golang.org/dl/) but I have not tried. It is generally not recommended to run the CockroachDB nodes on Windows.

You can find more details about the root of the problem in [this CockroachDB issue](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/32415)